# Is this a Blender 2.92 rotation issue?

Tags: versions

I am facing a rotation issue in Blender 2.92 and I would like to know if anyone else have the same issue.

Let's say I rotate a triangle at `-32.5d` and then I want to set it at `-45d` by typing it on redo panel. If I do that in Blender 2.91 or earlier version, it works fine...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ4z4VDb860

But in Blender 2.92, triangle rotates opposite...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9a7s4UcCNa4

Comment: Hey :). You're right, the rotation values are inverted in the popup panel. I'd suggest reporting a bug.

Comment: @JachymMichal I already did!!! :) https://developer.blender.org/T86333